# Android Studio Swipe Refresh

Tags: java, android, refresh, swipe

just wondering if anyone can help me with this, I'm trying to add a swipe to refresh function and I can't see where I'm going wrong, I just get the error message cannot resolve symbol mySwipeRefreshLayout

Heres the code. Thanks

```
public class eventsListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
        new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {

        refreshList();
    }
}

public class eventsListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
        new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {

        refreshList();
    }
}
```

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/activity_events_list"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context="com.parse.fypPlannr.eventsListActivity"
  android:background="#24B14D">

 <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
   android:id="@+id/Swiper"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ListView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:id="@+id/eventList"
   android:layout_below="@+id/createEvent"
   android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
<Button
   android:text="Map View"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/mapButton"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:background="#029789"
   android:textColor="#ffffbb33"
   android:onClick="mapView" />

<Button
   android:text="Log Out"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/logOut"
   android:onClick="logOut"
   android:background="#029789"
   android:textColor="#ffffbb33"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
   android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mapButton"
   android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/mapButton" />

<Button
   android:text="Create Event"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/createEvent"
   android:onClick="createEvent"
   android:background="#04988a"
   android:textColor="#ffffbb33"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mapButton"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/activity_events_list"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context="com.parse.fypPlannr.eventsListActivity"
  android:background="#24B14D">

 <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/Swiper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/eventList"
    android:layout_below="@+id/createEvent"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
<Button
    android:text="Map View"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mapButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#029789"
    android:textColor="#ffffbb33"
    android:onClick="mapView" />

<Button
    android:text="Log Out"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/logOut"
    android:onClick="logOut"
    android:background="#029789"
    android:textColor="#ffffbb33"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mapButton"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/mapButton" />

<Button
    android:text="Create Event"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/createEvent"
    android:onClick="createEvent"
    android:background="#04988a"
    android:textColor="#ffffbb33"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mapButton"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

​http://pastebin.com/u72WtQ3y​
Java Code

http://pastebin.com/9KnYhJLp
Xml​

Comment: I have edited your post it will be visible for a moment. And I have posted code inside your post. Make sure you put better explanation for the code and post your logcat and you can remove those links pointing to some webiste outside stackoverflow.

Comment: You need to declare a variable in Java before you use it. Your `mySwipeRefreshLayout` hasn't been declared in the current class or any of the super classes. Please spend some time working through the [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) before attempting Android, otherwise from now on you are going to have difficult problems everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need use of  implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener.

And I've not find another problem. Maybe There is wrong in refreshList(); method